# Trying to read value between span tags, into input box. Get a value of undefined onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make some sort of `num_pad`, but when I `click` one of the `buttons(0-9)`, my `displayBox` shows a value of undefined and not the number selected.

```
 <head>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function getValue() {
            var display = document.getElementById('displayBox').value += document.getElementsByTagName('span').innerHTML;
         }
         </script>
      </head>
      <body>

            <div class="display">
                <input type="text" id="displayBox"><br />
            </div>
            <div id="numbers" style="line-height: 55px;">
                <span onclick="getValue(this)">1</span>
                <span onclick="getValue(this)">2</span>
                <span onclick="getValue(this)">3</span>

            </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName()
```

will return an array of matching elements which you have to access using an index.

try

```
function getValue(elm) { //elm referes to the <span> which is clicked
 var display = document.getElementById('displayBox').value += elm.innerHTML;
}
```

instead.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2m3Uv/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code -> [Demo](http://jsbin.com/hizesizi/1/edit)

You pass an element to your function -> `getValue(this)`, but your getValue function `function getValue()` receives no argument.

Change it to `getValue(el)` <- `el` is the element that is being passed.

```
function getValue(el) {

    var display = document.getElementById('displayBox').value = el.innerHTML;

}
```

Besides, `document.getElementsByTagName(tagname)` returns a `HTML Collection` of found elements. To access any of those found elements you must use indexing -> `document.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0]` <- `[0]` refers to the first element of the `HTML Collection`. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)